# Passing object by const reference vs passing nameless object

Tags: c++, oop, reference, constants, pass-by-reference

C++11;

Given two classes, Class A and Class B, where Class A stores a data member of Class B, is it more efficient to;

1: Create an object of type B, and type A, then pass an object of type A a const reference to object of type B;

```
A storage;
B object(1,2,3);
storage.add(object);
```

2: Create an object of type A, and pass it a nameless object of type B, eg;

```
A storage;
storage.add(B(1,2,3));
```

Are these calls equal in terms of performance?

Now suppose if I wanted a vector in type A to store objects of type B that I pass into type A; Would I be making two copies of type B each call to storage.add(), regardless of whether I pass the storage object a reference to an already created object or pass an anonymous object directly to object of type A?

In the case of storing a vector of B objects in type A, would it be more efficient to pass a nameless object of type B, store them in the vector, and return pointers to the vector elements, or to create an object of type B, and pass a pointer to storage.add() and store my objects of type B in a vector of pointers?

I hope I've made my intentions clear. I'll post a code example if my intentions aren't too clear. I'm just not sure what the most efficient way is to pass objects around is when I also need to return them via calls to my storage class.

Comment: Your second sample isn't an example of passing an object of type A to B anonymously at all, it is the reverse. Your question remains obscure.

Comment: Also, you should specify whether C++ means C++11 (think move semantics), in which case an answer would likely be the opposite of the answer otherwise.

Comment: I meant C++11 yes. Sorry, I don't think I mean an anonymous object at all. I just mean initialising the object within the parameters. I think I mean nameless objects. I'll amend the question.

Comment: I think you forgot `A storage;` in the first code example.

Comment: @Jefffrey; well spotted. Now ammended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these calls equal in terms of performance?

In C++11 with the new move semantics, the performance is about the same. If you are using your own classes, make sure they implement a move constructor and a move assignment operator.

> In the case of storing a vector of B objects in type A, would it be more efficient to pass a nameless object of type B, store them in the vector, and return pointers to the vector elements, or to create an object of type B, and pass a pointer to storage.add() and store my objects of type B in a vector of pointers?

If you're refering to STL vectors, the best performance will be achieved with anonym objects, because otherwise, your object will be copied, as STL stores values, not references.

The rule of thumb for returning objects from a collection is to return them by *reference*. That's the pattern followed by STL [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/)

When you store pointers instead of values, you are changing the ownership of memory to the client of the vector class, because, normally, who creates an object should be responsible for deallocating it too.

Comment: So when I pass a nameless object to a class method that stores the object in an STL vector, I'm not making a copy? Whereas if I passed a named object, a copy would be made of the object passed to the STL vector in the class method? Have I got that right?